# Запрос к базе данных в Yii2, содержащий HAVING, COUNT, CASE и IN

Tags: sql, yii2

Как при помощи класса yii\db\Query сформулировать следующий запрос SQL:

```
SELECT `dish`.*
FROM `dish`
INNER JOIN `consist` ON `dish`.`id` = `consist`.`dish_id`
GROUP BY `dish`.`id`
HAVING COUNT(
    CASE WHEN `consist`.`ingredient_id` NOT IN (19, 20, 21) OR `consist`.`hidden` = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
    END
) = 0
```

Поясню, что тут происходит. Из таблицы блюд (`dish`) нужно выбрать те блюда, которые содержат только определённый набор ингредиентов (в данном случае это `19, 20, 21`, но этот набор может меняться), и не содержат другие ингредиенты. При этом ни один ингредиент не должен быть спрятан (`hidden`). `ingredient` - таблица ингредиентов, `consist` - таблица сочетаний блюд и ингредиентов.

Comment: А никак - запрос некорректен.

Comment: @Akina он исправно выполняется в phpMyAdmin

Comment: Ага, и даёт результат, не имеющий смысла. И то - работает исключительно потому, что не установлен ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. И до тех пор, пока хостер не изменит SQL Mode.

Comment: @Akina, хорошо, напишите, что конкретно здесь некорректно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+only_full_group_by - уже наступили. Ты пока стоишь в очереди...

Comment: @Akina послушайте, у меня нет сейчас времени во всех этих настройках разбираться, просто скажите, как правильно сделать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106889/discussion-between-pavel-sumarokov-and-akina).

Comment: Правильно - зависит от задачи. Либо замените ```SELECT dish.*``` на ```SELECT dish.id```, либо, если какие-то из полей тоже нужны - перечислите их в SELECT и в GROUP BY. В любом случае `SELECT *` и `GROUP BY` - это заботливо положенные грабли.

Comment: Оставил ````SELECT dish.id````, в Yii выдаёт пустой результат (хотя в phpMyAdmin работает правильно). Причём, когда в HAVING поменять OR на AND, то результат получается непустым, но бессмысленным